# Extract() position list

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Hi i try to extract info from a scrapy item.

I try

```
dre = [i.split(', ') for i in response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[contains(@class,"business-address")])').extract()]
    ml_item['address'] = dre[0]
```

output:

```
'address': ['Calle V Centenario 24', '46900', 'Torrente', 'Valencia']
```

I need save the info from this output  in a diferent variables comma delimited
`ml_item['cp'] = '46900'` , `ml_item['city'] = 'Torrente'`

Comment: `ml_item['cp'] = dre[1]` and `ml_item['city'] = dre[2]`

Comment: Is out of range

Comment: Please edit your question and provide context if you want someone to help. We can't guess what the code is supposed to do, when you're getting that error or what you really want to achieve

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex I think it has to be `dre[0][1]` and `dre[0][2]`

Comment: @furas that makes sense, indeed. Missed the assignment to `address`. Well spotted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dre[0]` gives you `['Calle V Centenario 24', '46900', 'Torrente', 'Valencia']` then

```
ml_item['cp']   = dre[0][1] 
ml_item['city'] = dre[0][2]
```

or

```
ml_item['address'] = dre[0]

ml_item['cp']   = ml_item['address'][1] 
ml_item['city'] = ml_item['address'][2]
```